# What bitrate should I use when extracting channel from mp2 to FLAC with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, flac, audio-conversion

I have a stereo mp2 audio that I want to extract the right channel to a mono FLAC audio. The detected info of the mp2 is this:

```
Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s
```

I ran the extract command but the output flac only has 128 kbps, is this bitrate okay or do I need a matching 224 kbps to retain all the information?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp2 -vn -map_channel 0.1.1 output.flac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLAC is lossless, and although it is compressed, [you don't need to set a bitrate](https://xiph.org/flac/faq.html#general__lowest_bitrate). Therefore, this encoder ignores the bitrate option (`-b:a`) if you try to use it.

The 128k you see in the console output is misleading in this case. It's just the default value that is chosen when `-b:a` is not set, but as already mentioned it is ignored by `-c:a flac` anyway.

So your command needs no changes regarding FLAC and bitrate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did a little test converting a 320k aac to FLAC with both compression level 0 and 8. Level 0 gave 1100 kbps and level 8 gave 900 kbps, so I guess that bitrate is just there to indicate the compression level.